# Using two similar collection view cells and thereby avoiding code duplication

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, uicollectionviewcell

I want to have two nearly similar cells. The difference is only in displaying one more view on it.

Therefore I thought to use a custom constructor. Normally you have a constructor similar to this one:

```
public class AnimalCell : UICollectionViewCell
{
    [Export ("initWithFrame:")]
    public AnimalCell (CGRect frame) : base (frame)
    {
        // do something
    }
}
```

I want to pass a type and depending on this type I want to display different items on the cell. The best way would be to use a constructor like this:

```
public AnimalCell(MyCustomType type)
{
    if(type == XXX){
        // add as subview, add constraints, ...
    }else{
        // normal setup
    }
}
```

I want to keep cell reuse of course. Can this be achived? How?

Another thing which comes to my mind is to use subclassing. Has anybody an idea how I can define *cell* so that I don't have to duplicate the same code? E.g.

```
var cell = null;
if (MyCustomType == XXX) {
    cell = collectionView.DequeueReusableCell (DefaultCell.Key, indexPath) as DefaultCell;
} else {
    cell = collectionView.DequeueReusableCell (CustomizedCell.Key, indexPath) as CustomizedCell;
}
cell.DoSomething("someValue"); // this doesn't work because you have to define cell with a certain class
// do some more initialization
```

**My current solution:**

```
public abstract class DefaultCell : UICollectionViewCell
{
    protected bool someVariable;

    [Export ("initWithFrame:")]
    public DefaultCell (CGRect frame) : base (frame)
    {
    }

    public void DoSomething(string text)
    {
        label.Text = text;
    }
}

public class Custom1Cell : DefaultCell
{
    public static readonly NSString Key = new NSString ("Custom1Cell");

    [Export ("initWithFrame:")]
    public Custom1Cell (CGRect frame) : base (frame)
    {
        initialize ();
    }

    private void initialize()
    {
        // some initialization
    }
}

public class Custom2Cell : DefaultCell
{
    public static readonly NSString Key = new NSString ("Custom2Cell");

    [Export ("initWithFrame:")]
    public Custom2Cell (CGRect frame) : base (frame)
    {
        initialize ();
    }

    private void initialize()
    {
        // some initialization
    }

    public void SomeMethod(string text)
    {
        if(someVariable)
            someOtherLabel.Text = text;
    }
}
```

The dequeuing works as described by Mahmoud:

```
DefaultCell cell;
if (type = XXX) {
    cell = collectionView.DequeueReusableCell (Custom1Cell.Key, indexPath) as Custom1Cell;
} else {
    cell = collectionView.DequeueReusableCell (Custom2Cell.Key, indexPath) as Custom2Cell;
}
cell.DoSomething("works on both cell types");
((Custom2Cell)cell).SomeMethod("works only on one cell type");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

maybe you consider an abstract class with shared variables and methods (name it BaseClass) and two other classes which inherits from abstract one and in the code you can define cell as an Object and initialize it in the if statement just like as below:

```
Object cell;
if (MyCustomType == XXX) {
    cell = new class1()
   ((Class1) cell).MethodInClass1();
} else{
   cell = new class2();
   ((Class2) cell).MethodInClass2();
}
```

Comment: Sounds reasonable. Now I tried it. One thing which is missing for me: I have defined my abstract class *Object*. How can I call `cell.DoSomething()` on *class2*? Because *DoSomething* is only defined in *class2* and not in the abstract class.

Comment: Object is a java type not your abstract class. you can name abstract class as with name BaseClass and as I mentioned in the if you can instantiate it from either calss1 or class2. 
when you want call method DoSomthing which is only belong to class 2, you must do as follow
((Class2) cell).DoSomething();
Also I edited my answer with regard to these comments!!!

Answer (score 1):

You can Add a UICollectionViewCell's Subclass let's say YourCell. Now give YourCell to the cell in the storyboard. And in YourCell you can add any number of views and you can Outlet them FROM your Storyboard cell TO the YourCell Class and then you can customise your view as you need.

**Updat:**
ok let say you don't add that view in the storyboard but you have it as a property(Which i just a pointer so wont take memory :) a lot  ) Just do lazy instantiation on the getter and set it's constraints in this getter methor. Here's an example of lazy instantiation we have a label which is not in storyboard view.

```
-(UILabel *)yourLabel
{
    if(!_yourLabel){
        _yourLabel=[[UILabel alloc]init];
        NSLayoutConstraint *leadingConstraint= [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.contentView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:_yourLabel attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading multiplier:1.0 constant:0];
         NSLayoutConstraint *topConstraint= [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.contentView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:_yourLabel attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop multiplier:1.0 constant:0];
        [self.contentView addConstraints:@[leadingConstraint,topConstraint]];
    }
    return _yourLabel;
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I could place a view on my cell and hide it (but it will always be created and consumes some performance/memory). Another thing would be to use a method which adds the view and rearranges all constraints. I'm looking for a more general purpose solution which would make it clear and simple (e.g. when there are more differences). But in general you're right.

Comment: I have updated my answer sorry i dont know swift much i hope you got the idea.

Comment: Ahh ok I get it. My code is not in Swift btw (its in C#), but that doesn't matter. Of course you can post Objective-C/Swift if you want :) For my case your solution would work. +1 If I'd have to make bigger changes in the structure I'd have to rearrange all other views and constraints too. Therefore I'm trying it with an abstract class now.